# Custom build task with junit5

Tags: gradle

Using gradle and junit 5 the sets up the regular `build` command to run all tests:

```
test {
    useJUnitPlatform()
    failFast = true
}
```

I also `@Tag("slow")` some tests that I want to skip sometimes, so I have a new task `testFast` to skip those tests:

```
task testFast(type: Test) {
    useJUnitPlatform {
        excludeTags 'slow'
    }
}
```

Great.  So now I want an additional `build` command, which does the same steps as the regular build command, but replaces the normal `test` steps with my `testFast` command.  How do I do this?

```
task buildFast(dependsOn: 'build') {
    // TODO replace the test task with testFast
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could probably do this via the [TaskExecutionGraph](https://docs.gradle.org/current/javadoc/org/gradle/api/execution/TaskExecutionGraph.html)

```
task buildFast(dependsOn: 'build') { 
    // no body required 
} 
gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    boolean fast = gradle.taskGraph.hasTask('buildFast')
    project.tasks['test'].enabled = !fast
    project.tasks['testFast'].enabled = fast
}
```